# When did the lightsaber become an icon of popular culture?

Tags: star-wars, history-of, lightsaber

The lightsaber is, almost unanimously, a universal icon of science fiction. The ultimate weapon belonging to a more civilised age. In its own way, it enjoyed a status and prestige akin to Darth Vader as the greatest villain of its time (if not still). It is a powerful symbol and idea that continues to the present day, extending far beyond the the Star Wars universe.

When did this begin? imo Ep IV hinted at the lightsaber's power but didn't do it justice. Not until Ep V.

Maybe one of the First Jedi can come forth and share your wisdom with us?

Comment: Seriously, why is this downvoted? It may not be in-universe stuff, but I've seen plenty of questions set in our real world.

Comment: Since the light saber was never seen before the trailer for Star Wars, one would assume that is when it started.  However, I deny it is "a universal icon of science fiction".  Maybe a universal icon of *Star Wars*?

Comment: “extending far beyond the the Star Wars universe” — does it? I don’t feel like similar ideas have been adopted in a lot of other fictional franchises.

Comment: The lightsaber is trademarked to Star Wars, yes, but it is present in many, many, many games. Not AAA titles from big companies who worry about intellectual property laws, mind you, but indie developers and hobbyists etc. as well as in videos people make and such. It is invariably a recognisable part of pop culture. That's how you see its significance in popular imagination. You don't need to know Star Wars to know the lightsaber. Everyone knows the laser sword that can cut through everything. That's what I mean by how it has spread beyond its existence within the Star Wars universe.

Comment: Well, I also reject the premise of the question.   I don't think it's any more iconic than a symbol of *Star Wars*.

Comment: Snarky addendum:   On the other kind, in the current anti-tag-proliferation climate, the existence of [tag:lightsaber] does appear to be an objective measure of its iconicity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As soon as *Star Wars* came out, kids all over the United States were pretending to wave light sabers around.  The movie was the first example of the mega-blockbuster film phenomenon, and it influenced popular culture in many ways.  One of those ways was that kids wanted to play Star Wars and fight with pretend light sabers.  The cool factor only intensified after *The Empire Strikes Back*, since that featured a light saber duel directly between Luke Skywalker and Vader.  By the time *Return of the Jedi* came out, the light saber was so emblematic of the *Star Wars* series that Episode VI theatrical poster consisted of a light saber and not that much else:

[image: ROTJ Poster]

Comment: Nice! Out of curiosity, good sir, were you one of them?

Comment: I was only a few years old when the first film came out, but I remember kids a couple years older playing Star Wars games as soon as the film came out.  (I didn't really understand what was going on, but I knew that playing Star Wars was a big deal.)  By the second movie, I was old enough to see it in the first theatrical run, and I was hooked on it from that point forward.

Comment: I added in the poster you were talking about just for a bit of "aesthetic coolness" ;)

Comment: Suddenly, it feels like it would be cool if they do the same thing for Ep IX, only this time with modern real photography photoshopped to match this poster rather than pure artwork. Rey's hands with her saber or something.